# Ajax call crashes the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create a comment system with ajax. The system makes an ajax call to post_comment.php where it does a INSERT INTO and returns the info I need.

Problem: the script seems not to work.. it just freezes my page, and if I wait it refreshes the page after 8 seconds.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function post()
{
  var comment = document.getElementById("content").value;
  if(comment)
  {
    $.ajax
    ({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'templates/post_comment.php',
      data: 
      {
         content:content,
         user_id:<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>,
         brand_id:<?php echo $_SESSION['brand_id']; ?>,
         ticket_id:<?php echo $_GET['unique_id']; ?>
      },
      success: function (response) 
      {
          console.log('okay response');
        document.getElementById("all_comments").innerHTML=response+document.getElementById("all_comments").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("content").value="";
        document.getElementById("username").value="";

      }, error: function() {
          alert("There was an error. Try again please!");
        }
    });
  }

  return false;
}
</script>
```

the only error (from google console) i see is the following: maximum call stack size exceeded jquery
it appears during the refresh, and then it disappears

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why `return false;` dose this have any impact?

Comment: Can you add your html code please? @Webdesigner i think it's to avoid submit from refreshing page

Comment: when is `post()` triggered? is it when the user clicks a button? the error you are getting means  that you are exceeding the limit of the browser's memory

Comment: What and how much content you have in response?

Comment: @MehdiBounya post() is added in the form (<form method='post' action="" onsubmit="return post();">)

Comment: @NitinDhomse the html response is this.. for example: https://www.ticketing.one/client/templates/post_comment.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in this line:

```
content:content,
```

Change that line to:

```
content: comment,
```

Please, change that line because **content** is an object and you cannot add an object inside another object. In **chrome last version** this object is the input **content** itself while in mozilla it refers to the window object.

I report this from MDN:

> [content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/content): Deprecated
>   This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Avoid using it and update existing code if possible; see the compatibility table at the bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time.

I'm sure you want to refer to **comment** variable.

```js
function post(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var comment = document.getElementById("content").value;
    //
    // the next line in order to show the type of content
    //
    console.log('content is : ' + typeof(content));
    if (comment) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'https://api.github.com/repositories',
            data: {
                since: '384',
                //
                // changed from content to comment
                //
                content: comment,
                user_id: 'id',
                brand_id: 'brand_id',
                ticket_id: 'unique_id'
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                console.log('okay response');
                document.getElementById("all_comments").innerHTML = response + document.getElementById("all_comments").innerHTML;
                document.getElementById("content").value = "";
                document.getElementById("username").value = "";

            },
            error: function () {
                alert("There was an error. Try again please!");
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form>
    content: <input type="text" id="content" value="content">
    all_comments: <input type="text" id="all_comments" value="all_comments">
    username: <input type="text" id="username" value="username">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" onclick="post(event);">
</form>
```

Comment: yess!! that was the problem... but not becauseof what you said... just because I used another name for the variableI wanted to use.. sorry :)